# Trying to docker pull <image:tag>, getting "Error "Error response from daemon: pull access denied"

Tags: docker-compose

Tried to pull a docker image a/b:1.1.1 from docker hub, with private repository.It is failing with below error message:

Error response from daemon: pull access denied for a/b, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

I have tried docker login, which gets succeeded. The built docker image is in docker hub. 
I am using Ubuntu 18.04 .
Dont know how to debug further.

Sequence of commands followed:

1. I have created
   `docker build --no-cache -t a/b:1.1.1`
2. `docker images`

Then 
`docker tag .... a/b:1.1.1`

Then
`docker push a/b:1.1.1`

3. Checked image in docker hub and it is there.
4. In different system, While trying
   `docker login`
   `docker pull a/b:1.1.1`

The above error message occurs.

Error response from daemon: pull access denied for {a/b image name} , repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

The docker image a/b:1.1.1 has to be listed in my current system docker images command.

Comment: DId you login to 'a'? How did you do that? Can you show all the commands you typed in?

Comment: I have logged in dockerhub.com . I found that under  a , b is there.


1. I have created
`docker build --no-cache -t a/b:1.1.1`

2. 
`docker push a/b:1.1.1` 
3. Checked image in docker hub and it is there.
4. In different system, While trying
`docker login`  
`docker pull a/b:1.1.1` 

The above error message occurs.